# mysql-docker-container - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

i am creating mysql docker container using below docker-compose file. Service is created successfully but when i am trying to enter inside the container getting the below error
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
docker container exec -it 966 /bin/bash
root@96607883960b:/# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@96607883960b:/# 



version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER="testpass"
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD="testpass"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="testpass"
    ports:
      - 33060:3306
    volumes:
      - /Users/hello/Work/Volumes/wavolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

i found many articles didn't help to resolve this issue

is any one having the solution for this issue ?

Comment: Remove the volume it might be caching some old pass and then try, `volumes:
      - /Users/hello/Work/Volumes/wavolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql` try with out this, if that did not work then try to add `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`

Comment: still same issue . i removed old volume

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your connection actually works and you can verify it running the following (service should be running already!):

```sh
docker-compose exec db sh -c 'mysql -uroot -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
```

The problem is that you are using the wrong password.

You can see your problem very easily by running `docker-compose config`. You will see in the output that the double quotes are included as part of the values.

This version should solve your issue:

```sh
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=testpass
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=testpass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testpass
    ports:
      - 33060:3306
    volumes:
      - /Users/hello/Work/Volumes/wavolumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mihai for this simple answer, actually spent almost 4 hrs trying to figure out what was happening with some of my containers not hooking the DB container, had made a simple error in one character on DB password.